# Update ListcollectionView based on current item of other ListCollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, collections

I want to Update ListCollectionView in a listbox each time the Item of another ListCollection gets selected.

I have 2 ListViewCollection, SceneCollectionView and ShotCollectionView. I want to have the SceneCollection filtered based on a property SceneNumber in ShotCollectionView, but I can get the ShotCollectionView to update when I go from one item to the other in SceneCollectionView.

This is my ViewModel

```
public class ShotListViewModel : NotifyUIBase
{
    public ListCollectionView SceneCollectionView { get; set; }
    private Scenes CurrentScene
    {
        get { return SceneCollectionView.CurrentItem as Scenes; }
        set { SceneCollectionView.MoveCurrentTo(value); RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Shot> _allShots = new ObservableCollection<Shot>();
    public ObservableCollection<Shot> AllShots
    {
        get { return _allShots; }
        set { _allShots = value; RaisePropertyChanged();}
    }

    private ListCollectionView _allShotsCollection;
    public ListCollectionView AllShotsCollection
    {
        get
        {
            if (_allShotsCollection == null)
            {
                _allShotsCollection = new ListCollectionView(this.AllShots);
                _allShotsCollection.Filter = IsSceneNumber;
            }
            return _allShotsCollection;
        }
    }

    private bool IsSceneNumber(object obj)
    {         
        if (obj as Shot != null
           && (obj as Shot).SceneNumber == (SceneCollectionView.CurrentItem as Scene).SceneNumber)
        {
            return true;                
        }
        return false;
    }


    public ShotListViewModel()
    {
        SceneCollectionView = Application.Current.Resources["SceneCollectionView"] as ListCollectionView;
        GetShotList(); //Populates the AllShots Observable collection.

        AddShotCommand = new RelayCommand(AddShot);
        FilterShotsCommand = new RelayCommand(AddShot);
    }
```

What am I missing here to make it work or is it better to use ICollectionViewLiveShaping. but I have no idea how to implement that

Answer (score 0):

I don`t understand what you tried to do, but lets talk on an example :

Lets say we have

`ListBox1` binded to **ListBox1Items** and
`ListBox2` binded to **ListBox2Items**.

if you want to filter the data from `ListBox2` you have to filter **ListBox2Items**. How to do that ? Is simple : `ListBox1` has a property ***SelectedItem*** which you can bind to --- lets say --- **ListBox1SelectedItem**. Every time when selection change, in the setter of the **ListBox1SelectedItem** you can trigger a filter on **ListBox2Items**.

Hope you understand what I`ve explained.